# Options to get a higher email send limit

Tags: email

Realize there a lot of bulk email services, but what I'm trying to do doesn't feel like bulk email; though maybe I'm just thinking about it the wrong way. Case in point, I attempted to create an account on MailChimp and it wants a subscriber list.

I'm send one, and only one email per address; for example, replying to job postings on Craigslist. I'm not sending follow-up emails, and basically the first email I send is the last to an address unless I get a reply.

Sometimes the email I send is based on a template, other times they've asked for something, and I customize the email. I've automated creating resumes and sending emails in the past, but currently the fastest way just seems to manually do it; meaning I can't imagine sending more than 500 emails in a single day.

As far as I'm able to tell if Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Lycos, AOL, etc. - do not offer the service of paying per email over the send limit, since I'd be willing to pay for the service and be done with this, as it's taking up a huge amount of time and overhead to deal with.

Currently, although I've seen sites giving higher numbers, most of the providers appear to limit emails sent to 20-40 a day; possible I'm doing something wrong, but if I am, I don't understand why these limits are not easy to see within an account, so I'm either able to stay within the limits, or see the service is not a good fit for my needs; currently I just get random error-messages, locked-out, etc.

(If needed, and the setup doesn't take more an a few hours, I'm more than willing to deal with configuring scripts, CSV files, templates, etc. on my computer - as long as they're well documented and the end result addresses the issue; meaning that if I have to send a one-off email, I just copy the template, make the changes, and point to the email. The system must also support attachments, since every email has at least one attachment; best solution would be if I'm able to load an attachment once to the system, then alias it in the local script.)

Comment: "I've automated creating resumes..." and replying to job adverts... 500 a day!? Really, have I read that correctly?! Wow, wish I could automate my job applications!

Comment: @w3d: The 500 is by hand, not automated; 2 emails a minute in four hours; it's not hard to do if you're not picky about the jobs you apply to and apply to any job you're able to do. If I automated it, it'd be 1000s of emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you limited to online email providers? You say you are willing to pay for a service...

A basic web hosting account (or email only account?) would enable you to set up any number of mailboxes and/or forwarders and would enable to you use any desktop email client, such as Mozilla Thunderbird which has a plethora of extensions available which might assist you in your job hunting quest.

A typical (shared) web host would have an email limit of 200-500 per hour - although this would naturally be something to check before signing up as they don't usually advertise this.

**Update**

Mozilla Thunderbird literally has [1000's of third party add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), from templates to [mail merge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/), so if there is a feature that is lacking you might be able to find a suitable add-on. TBH, I've not had the need to use many, although I do find [Send Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) useful, that as its name suggests, allows you to send the email at a later time or at a specific time. Rather than sending it in the middle of the night, when you might have written it, you can get it to send it first thing in the morning when people are awake.

Comment: +1 @w3d: Yes, I've thought about that, main issue is that approach requires a domain name, and oddly enough for personal emails "name@gmail.com" in my opinion is the professional standard. Finding a professional, short domain would hard to find. And a short domain like "name@z3.com" would look unprofessional and might even be seen as unsecure; z-3 is taken by the way, lol. What are the extensions you referenced?

Comment: @blunders: Well, this may be a matter of opinion, but I would have said that sending emails from your own domain would be more 'professional' than "name@gmail.com", which is essentially a disposable email address. In my opinion you would use a gmail address if you don't have your own domain. Not a domain like "z3", but what about your full name? eg. contact@yourfullname.me - may be .me since it is for personal correspondence? Btw... I use gmail, but I use my domains email address, which gmail allows you to do. (I've updated my answer regarding Thunderbird)

Comment: Thanks for all the additional info, selected as you as the answer, and +1 to the comment above. As for the domain suggest, my first-last name combo is both long and common; meaning 16 letters plus. That said, getting a domain appears to be the only real way to send more mail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with sending a lot of emails is you will inevitably end up being false positived by spam filters on the recipient's end.

If you want to send a lot of emails, and have a high percentage of those emails actually reach the destination, then you need to be an expert on spam or outsource the email sending process to someone who is an expert.

It sounds like you've tried MailChimp. It has an API. Their competitors also have API - I've had good experience with campaign monitor in the past, and I've heard MailRoute is very good (I would probably look into MailRoute first).

Use their API to add the email to the system, send the email, and then perhaps remove the customer right away. It shouldn't be too much work to create such a script, if you've got some experience with any scripting language.